# Synchronize leaflet map on two different browser tab

Tags: javascript, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am using leaflet, javascript, and react. The leaflet has a plugin called [Leaflet sync](https://github.com/jieter/Leaflet.Sync/blob/master/L.Map.Sync.js.).
This plugin sync two or more map [demo](http://jieter.github.io/Leaflet.Sync/examples/dual.html). I want to synchronize the map in two different browsers' tabs. Leaflet sync does not work in two different tabs. Here is my code so far [Code Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/leaflet-pr-xybdaf-9dx3e2?file=/src/App.tsx).

```
        import React, { useEffect } from "react";
        import L, { LatLngTuple } from "leaflet";
        import { FC, useState } from "react";
        import { MapContainer } from "react-leaflet";
        import "./styles.css";
        // import "leaflet.sync";
        import MapContent from "./MapContent";
        import styled from "styled-components";
        import { Link, HashRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
        import MapOne from "./MapOne";
        import MapTwo from "./MapTwo";
        
        
        export default function App() {
          const [center] = useState<LatLngTuple>([0, 0]);
          const [bounds] = useState([
            [432205, 6475078],
            [437720, 6481113]
          ]);
          const [zoom] = useState(0);
          const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
          const [mapA, setMapA] = useState<any>();
          const [mapB, setMapB] = useState<any>();
        
          return (
            <Router>
              <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
                <Link to="/mapone" target="_blank">
                  Open Map One
                </Link>
                <Link to="/maptwo" target="_blank">
                  Open Map Two
                </Link>
              </div>
        
              <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/mapone" element={<MapOne />} />
                <Route exact path="/maptwo" element={<MapTwo />} />
              </Routes>
            </Router>
          );
        }
    
       
    

        

                

        
 // MapOne.tsx
            export default function MapOne() {
              const [center] = useState<LatLngTuple>([0, 0]);
              const [bounds] = useState([
                [432205, 6475078],
                [437720, 6481113]
              ]);
              const [zoom] = useState(0);
              const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
              const [mapA, setMapA] = useState<any>();
              const [mapB, setMapB] = useState<any>();
            
              useEffect(() => {
                if (mapA) {
                  mapA.fitBounds(bounds);
                }

                // This does not work since mapB exist in another tab    
                // if (mapA && mapB) {
                //   mapA.sync(mapB);
                //   mapB.sync(mapA);
                //   mapA.fitBounds(bounds);
                // }
              }, [mapA, mapB, bounds]);
            
              return (
                <StyledDiv>
                  <h1>Map One</h1>
                  <MapContainer
                    whenReady={() => setLoaded(true)}
                    whenCreated={setMapA}
                    center={center}
                    zoom={zoom}
                    scrollWheelZoom={true}
                    placeholder={<MapPlaceholder />}
                    crs={L.CRS.Simple}
                    minZoom={-4}
                  >
                    <MapContent loaded={loaded} bounds={bounds} />
                  </MapContainer>
                </StyledDiv>
              );
            }
        
   

   // MapTwo.tsx

    export default function MapTwo() {
      const [center] = useState<LatLngTuple>([0, 0]);
      const [bounds] = useState([
        [432205, 6475078],
        [437720, 6481113]
      ]);
      const [zoom] = useState(0);
      const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
      const [mapA, setMapA] = useState<any>();
      const [mapB, setMapB] = useState<any>();
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (mapB) {
          mapB.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
    
        // if (mapA && mapB) {
        //   mapA.sync(mapB);
        //   mapB.sync(mapA);
        //   mapA.fitBounds(bounds);
        // }
      }, [mapA, mapB, bounds]);
    
      return (
        <StyledDiv>
          <h1>Map Two</h1>
    
          <MapContainer
            whenReady={() => setLoaded(true)}
            whenCreated={setMapB}
            center={center}
            zoom={zoom}
            scrollWheelZoom={true}
            placeholder={<MapPlaceholder />}
            crs={L.CRS.Simple}
            minZoom={-4}
          >
            <MapContent loaded={loaded} bounds={bounds} />
          </MapContainer>
        </StyledDiv>
      );
    }
```

How can I use `mapA.sync(mapB)` to sync maps in two different browsers' tabs. I think I cannot since both are isolated from each other.

How can I achieve the same functionality as in leaflet sync but with different browser tabs?

Comment: You will probably have to create a api to let the two clients communicate with each other.

Comment: One browser tab does not have access to information from another browser tab, for security reasons.  As @Disco recommended, you would need one map to send data to a third party application (a server, for example), which then streams that back to all tabs currently connected to it.